# Is it possible to use web workers with JavaScript that isn't contained in an external file?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I'm trying to use web workers in a way that doesn't require an external file as the code for the worker, is this possible or does a solution already exist to pipe dynamic code into a web workers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this but I'm not sure how well supported it is, moreover it's no longer `BlobBuilder` but `Blob`.
There will come in handy:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers#Spawning_subworkers
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-enviornment-subworkers
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/Don-t-Build-Blobs-Construct-Them

Comment: Thanks, marked this as correct, the second link was particularly helpful.